# Electron cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, electron

For electron cookie I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-cookies

Then added this into my html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require('electron-cookies')
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
                        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
                    }

                    function getCookie12(name) {
                      var regexp = new RegExp("(?:^" + name + "|;\s*"+ name + ")=(.*?)(?:;|$)", "g");
                      var result = regexp.exec(document.cookie);
                      alert(document.cookie);
                      return (result === null) ? null : result[1];
                    }
    </script>
```

and called the methods :

```
<button onclick="createCookie('ppkcookie','testcookie',7)">Set Cookie</button>
<button onclick="getCookie12('ppkcookie')">Get Cookie</button>
```

but the `alert(document.cookie)`
shows me only

`ppkcookie` not `ppkcookie=testcookie`

Any ideas why?

Many thanks

Comment: why you aren't using the cookies provided properly by electron?

Comment: Hello, do you have any link how to do it.

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval I think electron-cookie is good for managing origin usefull on rest calls to a service, or is it completely useless?
(Here it was a removed comment about var, it applys to let and const, not var, sorry)

Answer (score 5):

This is how electron handles his own cookies.

```
var session = require('electron').remote.session;
var ses = session.fromPartition('persist:name');
```

This is how to set a cookie

```
     function setCookie(data, name) {
        var expiration = new Date();
        var hour = expiration.getHours();
        hour = hour + 6;
        expiration.setHours(hour);
        ses.cookies.set({
            url: BaseURL, //the url of the cookie.
            name: name, // a name to identify it.
            value: data, // the value that you want to save
            expirationDate: expiration.getTime()
        }, function(error) {
            /*console.log(error);*/
        });
    }
```

This is how to get the value of the cookie

```
    function getCookie(name) {
        var value = {
            name: name // the request must have this format to search the cookie.
        };
        ses.cookies.get(value, function(error, cookies) {
            console.console.log(cookies[0].value); // the value saved on the cookie
        });
    }
```

For more information about the cookies of electron you can read [here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/session/#class-cookies)

Comment: Hello, if you have time, I have another question: If i try to use   const {session} = require('electron');
in a static html it provides that session is undefiend..... any idea?

Comment: i've faced same problem, but i don't know why that's not working, in my example i figured out how to call it from a html or an external js file

Comment: Other question :) Sorry... I have managed to do separate html that call the js that has the methods... everything ok, I set and get the cookie, but if I close the app, open it again and then  and try to do GET again it is not working :(...

Comment: that's because they aren't being persisted fine, try to add the expirationDate so they can persist.

Comment: the problem that I found is that in the js i have the method get with return, after closing the app if I try to call it again form html the return is undefind :(

Comment: uhm that's weird, i've had a lot of problem for the persist of the cookies because they doesn't delete and you have the oposite problem. Uhm did you tried to call to all the cookies? with the params empty?

Comment: What is the BaseUrl? And how do I figure that out?

Comment: Also if you are using AngularJS. A cookies.get needs to return a promise.

Comment: BaseUrl it's the url from you get the cookie. And i use promises to get my cookie in angular, because it doesn't persist in an async call