# How to set a cookie in Electron Framework?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, xhtml, electron

I'm programming an application with Electron Framework (https://electronjs.org/).

What I want to do is just to set a cookie locally for the application and read it back next time .

I don't know how to achieve that. This: [Electron cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332058/electron-cookie) doesn't seem to work. When I call getCookie('cookiename') my code is stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: why dont u use localStorage?

Comment: What version of electron are you using ?

Comment: @Ammar: Thanks, that's a better solution.