# Access renderer process cookies by electron's main process

Tags: node.js, electron

I've got some issues with authentication (using cookies and session) and my electron-app

**The use case:**

1. User logs in
2. Session created and cookie is stored. (by app-bl module)

I read about `electron-session` and `electron-cookies` (https://electronjs.org/docs/all?query=coo#class-cookies) but nothing works.

Application structure:

```
electron-app
---express-app
------app-bl
------react-client
```

Electron version: 3.0.13

I used this to use express within electron:
https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express

It seems like electrons main process doesn't know about cookies created by the rendered process.

**electron/main.js:**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow, session } = electron

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  const screenElectron = electron.screen;
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    icon: `${__dirname}/assets/icon.ico`
  });
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  mainWindow.on("close", () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send("stop-server");
  });
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show()
  })
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
```

**express-app/index.js:**

```
const ev = require('express-validation');
const Path = require('path')

const Express = require('express')
const BodyParser = require('body-parser')
const CookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const Session = require('express-session');

const App = require('./app/index.js')

// Init server
const express = Express()
const router = Express.Router()
const port = parseInt(process.argv[2]) || process.env.PORT || 5001
const ip = "0.0.0.0"

express.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
express.use(BodyParser.json())
express.use(CookieParser())
express.use(Session({
    key: 'sessionId',
    secret: 'key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        expires: 600000
    }
}))

// Init Application
const app = App({ express, router })


// Static content
express.use(Express.static(Path.join(__dirname, './client/dist')))
express.use('/*', Express.static(Path.join(__dirname, './client/dist/index.html')))


// Error handler
express.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err)
    if (err instanceof ev.ValidationError) {
        return res.status(err.status).json({
            status: err.status,
            message: err.statusText
        });
    }
    return res.status(err.status).json({
        status: err.status,
        message: err.message
    });
});

(async () => {
    try {
        await app.init()
        const server = await app.start(ip, port);
        console.log("Server started http://%s:%s", ip, port)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})()
```

And this is how I'm creating the session after successful login in **app-bl** module:

```
async function loginHandler(req, res, next) {
    const username = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password
    try {
        const user = await authService.login(username, password)
        req.session.userId = user.id;
        res.json({ user })
    } catch (error) {
        error.status = 500
        next(error)
    }
}
```

I managed to create cookies inside main process and I can see then using `console.log`, but nothing is showing inside `devTools`, I tried this code:

```
const mainSession = mainWindow.webContents.session
const cookie = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8000',
  name: 'sessionId',
  domain: 'localhost',
  expirationDate: 99999999999999
}
mainSession.cookies.set(cookie, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
})

mainSession.cookies.get({}, (error, cookies) => {
  console.log(cookies)
})
```

I have the feeling I'm missing something here.

Comment: if you want to access main process vars, use REMOTE: var session = require('electron').remote.session; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332058/electron-cookie

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio My renderer process spwans new child process (this is the express-app module I described above - electron-with-express), this is where the cookies are created. I need the electron app to know about those cookies.

Comment: Did you figure this out ever?

Comment: @Noitidart Not really, I have ended up with different authentication strategies but still hoping for a good solution

Answer (score 0):

This package works: https://github.com/heap/electron-cookies

It seems to use Local Storage to emulate cookies. So you can read/write cookies using normal JavaScript syntax, and hopefully your application won't know the difference.